# How do you make an UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyleValue1) in-place editing of the detailTextLabel (such as a passowrd for an email account)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, settings

UITableViewCell of type UITableViewCellStyleValue1 is what is used in the Settings of the iPhone/iPad.  I would like to know how to make a UITableViewCell that allows you to edit in-place a secure string (showing dots instead of actual text) in the detailTextLabel similar to the setting of the password field in creation of a new email account for the iPhone.

Anyone have any idea how this is done?

Thanks in advance,

Shiun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. Place a `UITextField` with no border in the cell. Make the cell the text field's delegate so that the cell can handle the case when the user taps and edits the text field. Whenever the user updates the text field, the cell should probably inform the table view controller (through the delegate pattern or a custom notification) so that the view controller can save the new value.

Also, in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, the view controller should bring up the keyboard for the text field (`-becomeFirstResponder`).

Comment: Ok.... I forgot to mention that UITableView will comprise of cells that will have the need for this interactivity while others will need to default to the UITableViewCellStyle1 where the detailTextLabel will need to be used to display actual text that's not user interact-able.  I guess I can enable/disable hide/show the UITextField of the subclass depending on which cells need this functionality.  Thanks, I'll give your suggestion a try

Comment: You can decide in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` based on `indexPath` which kind of cell to create. Just give the two types different reuse identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and further suggestion.  I just implemented it as you indicated and it works :-)